# High Sierra lockscreen appears about one minute or more after waking the computer and interacting with it

Tags: high-sierra, sleep-wake, lockscreen

After waking my macbook air from sleep I can immediately interact with visible apps and launch new ones -- but I can't type, click on webpages, switch spaces/desktops or enter fullscreen. After minutes or perhaps a random amount of time the lockscreen appears. This has happened multiple times, and seems more common after a long sleep.

Last time it happened the lockscreen never appeared by itself and I had to press the power button twice to get to it and unlock the system in order to use it fully.

I find this a bit weird, not to mention unusable. I don't even require the password after sleep in system settings.

**Is this a known problem? Are there workarounds?**

I'm using High Sierra. Updating to Mojave is not an option.

### Update

It seems that I am also unable to enable the security option to require password after sleep or screensaver. As soon as I check the checkbox it unchecks itself.